# how to suspend addEventListener for half a second?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, fetch-api

I have this code (working fine) :

```js
chiffreId.addEventListener('input', function () {
  fetch(url).then((response) =>
    response.json().then(data => {
      this.value = String(data.montant).replace(/\./, ','), //replace . with , for EU
        soldeId.innerHTML = data.solde;
    })
  );
});
```

how do I suspend the execution of the `fetch` code for half a second?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the `fetch` only in a timeout, and clear the timeout and start a new one every time the event fires.

You can also avoid one level of the `.then` nesting by returning the `.json` Promise:

```
let timeoutId;
chiffreId.addEventListener('input', function () {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.value = String(data.montant).replace(/\./, ','); //replace . with , for EU
                soldeId.innerHTML = data.solde
            });
    }, 500);
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `setTimeout` method to execute a function after a given time. The parameter `time` should be in milliseconds.

Try this:-

```
chiffreId.addEventListener('input' , function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
        fetch(url).then((response) =>
            response.json().then(data => {
                this.value = String(data.montant).replace(/\./,','), //replace . with , for EU
                soldeId.innerHTML = data.solde
            })
            )
}, 500)
    })
```

Comment: Learn about promise chaining.  It's worth understanding how promises work.